# How to capture any slf4j log.error() call in a Rest api using Prometheus metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a requirement that for a particular API*(which involves multiple classes and methods)*, if it fails due to any condition *(there will be n number of conditions/validations in end to end API)*, I need to capture this in Prometheus.
During this validation failure, I cannot fail my API, means API code will keep on working further *(hence http_server_request** metrics wont help)*.

So I want to increment some counter which will increase everytime whenever log.error() gets invoked in my full api code. and if that counter value increase beyond a threshold (say 10 value in last 15 mins), I need to create a Prometheus alert.

Is there a way to achieve it in some generic way?

Comment: Having your tests depend on logging is a bad idea. Instead, implement some way to check if the error condition is hit. Perhaps a Mockito spy?

Comment: There is a Prometheus metric named "logback_events_total" present which I can use, but it gives data at application level by default. It doesn't give data at a single level label.  May be sam customization can be done to use it mertic are a single flow level.